# Remove fields in embeddable (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to remove a list that is in an embeddable by removing the embeddable from the entity. This isn't working.. All the entities in the list are still in de database.

Code:

Method where it all starts:

```
 //attached entity
 Ship ship = findShip();
 ship.removeItinerary();
```

Ship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SHIP")
public class Ship extends Domain {

   @Embedded
   private Itinerary itinerary;


   public void removeItinerary() {
      this.itinerary = null;
   }
```

}

Itinerary:

```
@Embeddable
public class Itinerary implements Serializable {

   //tried orphanRemoval and cascade but without luck 
   //(since I'm not removing the Ship it's actually logic that it's not working..)
   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name = "SHIP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
   private List<Stop> stops = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

JPA 2.0

Comment: I've finally figured out what I was doing wrong.. I was always saving a new Itinerary() to the ship. The error actually isn't in this code.

For others: The combination of orphanRemoval and cascade.update does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If the itinerary is already saved to the database, you need to `delete` it. Eg, something like

```
public void removeItinerary() {
   getEntityManager().remove(this.itinerary);
   this.itinerary = null;
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to remove something that isn't an entity.

Comment: @NeilStockton that's great but then the entity manager doesn't know about it. Workarounds are never solutions

Comment: Then ignore the previous downvote.. But as @Gimby says indeed.. That was what I was going to reply now ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try to merget the ship entity after the call at removeItinerary method.

```
Ship ship = findShip();
ship.removeItinerary();
em.merge(ship).
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is not possible... can you try to clear the stops list before you set the itinerary to null... ? (in combination with orphanRemoval on the @JoinColumn...)

!! i have never testet this... !!

something like this:

```
public void removeItinerary() {
   this.itinerary.stops.clear();
   this.itinerary = null;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it without succes. Forgot to mention this in the question